# After swiping from Question to Answers, can no longer scroll question vertically

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After you swipe to show the answers to a question, you can't swipe to get back, and the question will no longer be scrollable.

To reproduce:

- Open a question that has answers
- Swipe from right to left to reveal the answers

  - note that you cannot swipe left to right back to the question
- click "Question" at the top of the page

  - now you can't scroll the page vertically

Using version 0.1.54

Comment: Nor can you vote then! Reproduced on 0.1.54.

Comment: I can reproduce it even on a question without any answers (after some swiping) e.g. this one on 0.1.54

Comment: I'm looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version **0.1.57.**

Note that I was able to reproduce the issue in the title ("can no longer scroll question vertically") but I wasn't able to reproduce one of the problems indicated in your second bullet:

> - note that you cannot swipe left to right back to the question

If this issue reappears, please submit another bug report.

Comment: Appears to be fixed. Great!