# In the feed, clicking a comment to a now deleted answer leads to a frozen view (no scrolling) of a wrong answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

*How to reproduce*:

1. Open the feed
2. Click on a comment to the answer that is now deleted

*What I expect to happen*: the link leads to the comment or a some indication is shown that the comment is deleted (because its answer is deleted).

*What happens instead*: shown the wrong answer *and* the scrolling doesn't work (frozen). If I switch to the question tab then the scrolling works; if I switch back to the answers tab; the scrolling stops working again (on the same wrong answer).

"frozen" scrolling means that I can't move the answer text at all (not even a pixel).

ios app version: 0.1.55

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue with just a different way of triggering it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229984/after-swiping-from-question-to-answers-can-no-longer-scroll-question-vertically

Comment: The wrong answer doesn't get highlighted as if it were the one you'd linked to, does it? It just doesn't scroll off the first answer?

Comment: The common part is that the scrolling is frozen completely (no movement at all). But it is a different issue e.g., I can vote on the (wrong) answer with the frozen scrolling, I can't vote on the frozen question from another issue.

Comment: I"m taking a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch! This was an edge case that needed patching.

**Fixed in version 0.1.57.** (will be released in the next few days)

Comment: I've checked (thanks to @Kasra Rahjerdi) and now clicking on a comment to a deleted answer still leads to the wrong answer without any indication that something is wrong but the view is not frozen now (version: 0.1.60)